# Can anyone explain this odd Galactic dust filament near the LMC?

Tags: dust

Perusing the Planck 353 GHz polarisation Aitoff projection I noticed an apparent magnetically driven dust filament rising abruptly from the Galactic ß-field in the Chameleon-Mensa S polar region. It streams for ~25° before dwindling in Eridanus. It appears to be associated with Galactic cirrus clumps 80 PC below the disc plane. The [Planck 353 GHz image is here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wqh7glVXZD7POVy5AEVAfDc2kZvu32F-), and a quickie [Chromoscope survey in optical, NIR, FIT mm/µm, and 21 cm is here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GcMCcmVR-xoJB828UpE_XEsCA9KAeVX4). It is mentioned in only a few papers incl. Besla/Martinez-Delgado 2015, but there has been no specific study of its unusual morphology. It looks like a magnetically driven jet but originates from a region devoid of high-energy activity. If it is a Birkeland current it is a very odd one. I wonder if it is an old SN 1a remnant of the Hercules Loop and Aquila Rift type based on faint extinction filaments in Schlegel 1998 S Polar projection and 4 other Planck Aitoffs which seem to suggest traces of an old circular feature. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm getting a 404 on both of the links in this question, does anyone know of working links?